# Big query: LEFT OUTER JOIN cannot be used without a condition that is an equality of fields from both sides of the join

Tags: google-bigquery

Help, please. I created the next query but gen issue and I don`t understand how to fix it
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/geKmC.png)

```
SELECT
tb1.*
FROM
(SELECT
tb1.date,
  clientId,
  REGEXP_EXTRACT (hits.pagePath,"^([^\?]+)\?")  as page_url,
  hits.type as type,
  hits.eventInfo.eventCategory AS eventCategory,
  hits.eventInfo.eventAction AS eventAction,
  hits.eventInfo.eventLabel AS person_email,
FROM
  `table` AS tb1, UNNEST (hits) AS hits) as tb1


  where tb1.type = "pageview" or (tb1.eventCategory = "Enroll_Free_lecture" and 
  exists (select tb2.date, tb2.type from(select date, hitss.type as type  From `table`
  as tb2, UNNEST(hits) as hitss) tb2 where tb2.date <= tb1.date and tb2.type = "pageview" ))
```

Comment: Can you please paste the code as text instead of image?

Answer (score 1):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT * EXCEPT(flag)
FROM (
  SELECT
    tb1.date,
    clientId,
    REGEXP_EXTRACT (hits.pagePath,"^([^\?]+)\?")  AS page_url,
    hits.type AS type,
    hits.eventInfo.eventCategory AS eventCategory,
    hits.eventInfo.eventAction AS eventAction,
    hits.eventInfo.eventLabel AS person_email,
    COUNTIF(type = "pageview") OVER(ORDER BY `date`) AS flag
  FROM `table` AS tb1, 
  UNNEST (hits) AS hits
)
WHERE type = "pageview" OR (
  eventCategory = "Enroll_Free_lecture" 
  AND flag > 0
)
```

Comment: But Could you please help more! I add a description to questions

Comment: Yes sure. Thank you so much

Comment: I post new questions